# Issue when trying to recover a backup of GitLab for Docker

Tags: windows, docker, gitlab

Due to maintenance issues, I had to restore the equipment to factory condition. Before that, a backup copy of the container he had with GitLab was made through the following steps:

```
docker commit -p  78727078a04b  gitlab_backup

docker save -o /container_backup.tar gitlab_backup
```

And I've saved the .tar file.

Well, once I have left the computer as new. One of the most notable changes I have is that I changed the internal static ip I had. If before it was 192.168.0.177 it is now 192.168.0.198.

After installing docker again, I started importing the copy with the following steps:

```
docker load -i /container_backup.tar
```

And this is where I doubt if I am creating a container correctly from this image. This is what I do:

```
docker run --detach 
--hostname localhost 
--publish 443:443 --publish 7842:80 --publish 2098:22 
--name gitlab --restart always gitlab_backup:latest
```

The container is created and runs, but at the time of accessing with the browser it tells me that this page does not work. If I create a container from the official image of GitLab, it works well, but with this I can not recover what I had.

Thanks in advance.